# R function scope

Tags: function, r

I am trying to create a function for a series of rounding work in R, I have percentage, decimals, etc, each of them need to be rounded differently.

I start writing the function by first picking up the object I want, but I fail to do that already, here's the code:

```
roundings <- function(obj.head)
                     {obj.list <- ls(pattern=obj.head)
                      obj.list
                     }
```

Suppose I have two object `A1` and `B1`, I suppose if I run `roundings("A")`, `A1` should appear as the function output, but it didn't.

What have I done wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Not sure where you are going with this function, but I suspect you'll want to employ `get(obj.list)` to operate on the contents of `A1` at some point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call to `ls` is searching the *current* environment within the function and does not find any objects to match. You can specify the `envir` parameter in `ls` with `.GlobalEnv`. Thus your code becomes:

```
roundings <- function(obj.head)
{
    obj.list <- ls(pattern = obj.head, envir = .GlobalEnv)
    obj.list
}
```

Comment: thanks, and I give preference to answer by peoples other than me :)

Answer (score 2):

I found the reason, I should have added `envir=.GlobalEnv` inside the `ls` parameters.